# chef run error "ERROR: No parent found for monit_config[dsk-client]"

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, monit

while running chef in vagrant, I'm getting the following error

```
node-0: ERROR: No parent found for monit_config[dsk-client]
node-0: FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

the resource that triggers that looks as follows:

```
include_recipe 'tomk-monit'

monit_config 'dsk-client' do
    cookbook 'tomk-monit'
    source 'dsk-client.conf.erb'
end
```

(in the recipe tomk-monit there is an include statement for poise-monit)

The error itself is very unclear, and points to something in poise which I know nothing about.

is there something I'm missing here? something I should have added but didn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check that there is an `include_recipe` where you think there is. The `monit_config` resource needs a `monit` resource to exist before it can do its thing (so it knows where to put the config and whatnot).

In general if you have questions about my cookbooks just ping me on Slack, it's faster :)

Comment: Close! It was indeed the `include_recipe` thing. it's just the the `tomk-monit` itself was including the recipe above before including `poise-monit`